# How to tell if WikiCorpus from gensim is working?

Tags: python, gensim

I downloaded the full wikipedia archive 14.9gb and I am running thise line of code:

```
wiki = WikiCorpus("enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2")
```

My code doesn't seem to be getting past here and it has been running for an hour now, I understand that the target file is massive, but I was wondering how I could tell it is working, or what is the expected time for it to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often use an OS-specific monitoring tool, such as `top` on Linux/Unix/MacOS systems, to get an idea whether your Python process is intensely computing, using memory, or continuing with IO.

Even the simple vocabulary-scan done when 1st instantiating `WikiCorpus` may take a long time, to both decompress and tokenize/tally, so I wouldn't be surprised by a runtime longer than hour. (And if it's relying on any virtual-memory/swapping during this simple operation, as may be clear from the output of `top` or similar monitoring, that'd slow things down even more.)

As a comparative baseline, you could time how long decompression-only takes with a shell command like:

```
% time bzcat enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 | wc
```

(A quick test on my MacBook Pro suggests 15GB of BZ2 data might take 30-minutes-plus just to decompress.)

In some cases, turning on Python logging at the `INFO` level will display progress information with `gensim` modules, though I'm not sure `WikiCorpus` shows anything until it finishes. Enabling `INFO`-level logging can be as simple as:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: after running for 8 hours, I got a memory error on my windows pc. I have 16gb of ram, do you know how I would overcome this issue?